# How to parse a Date+Time String

Tags: java

Using java I need to parse this `2014-08-31 13:53:42.0` to `31-AUG-14 01.53.42 PM`

Comment: Do search for `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: but allready i have a date in String format "2014-08-31 13:53:42.0" i need this to convert

Comment: You're missing the point.  Trying to "format" a `String` is right pain in the backend.  Start by getting the `String` value into a more malleable format which will provide you with more options as how to format it the way you want to.  `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't just format a value, it can convert it from a `String` to a `Date` object...

Answer (score 5):

Start by doing some research into [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) which can be used to parse `String` values of a verity of formats into a `java.util.Date`.

You can then use another `SimpleDateFormat` to format the value to the format that you want, for example

```
try {
    String in = "2014-08-31 13:53:42.0";
    SimpleDateFormat sdfIn = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
    Date date = sdfIn.parse(in);
    System.out.println(date);
    SimpleDateFormat sdfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm.ss a");
    System.out.println(sdfOut.format(date));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
}
```

Which outputs

```
Sun Aug 31 13:53:42 EST 2014
31-Aug-14 01:53.42 PM
```

Comment: I think it's better if we don't provide full solutions for question like that.

Comment: @MarounMaroun If you can find a duplicate, please tell me and I'll delete the answer and close the question

Comment: Your answer is good since it contains explanation and not only code, it's detailed one, +1. But I think that OP might always think that he shouldn't do research and ask questions here with minimal understanding.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I'd prefer more research as well, it's a common problem with a common solution ;) - But teaching myself Objective C at the moment, what might seem simple to your mean, isn't always that simple for other people.  That's when I search SO ;)

Comment: @MarounMaroun What you say is true but Stackoverflow is meant to provide answer to coding queries asked by users, if a user asks his homework or anything else without research its his loss. Maybe this user did a lot of research and could not find solution, or maybe he didn't. If we start assuming many questions may remain unanswered. +1 for the answer BTW